# Azure DevOps - Select distinct IterationPath (workitems table)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to make in Python a distinct of all the possibilities of the IterationPath field and I am not able to obtain such data. I tried to use UNNEST to get the array it is in but I was unsuccessful. Can anyone help me with this?

```
query_wiql = Wiql(query="""\
SELECT distinct [System.IterationPath] FROM workitems
""")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get all the possibilities of the `IterationPath` field in current team project, you can try:

```
SELECT
        [System.IterationPath]
FROM workitems
WHERE
        [System.TeamProject] = @project
ORDER BY [System.ChangedDate] DESC
```

And if you want to get all the possibilities of the `IterationPath` field in current organization, you can use:

```
SELECT
        [System.IterationPath]
FROM workitems
ORDER BY [System.ChangedDate] DESC
```

If you don't want the order, you can delete the `ORDER BY [System.ChangedDate] DESC`. Hope it helps and if I misunderstand anything, feel free to correct me.

Comment: This unfortunately does not suit me because I would like to create an automatic list from this data. In addition, there is a limit of 20,000 records per query that I would pass.

Comment: I'm not sure about what the automatic list mean... Can you share some details about that, also, you can check if Shamrai's answer makes some help. Just a reminder :)

Comment: I think the problem here is that you don't get a distinct list of Iteration Paths.  Instead, you get the Iteration Paths of all the work items, with hundreds or thousands of duplicates.  WIQL seems to be sorely lacking the DISTINCT keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Classification Nodes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/classification%20nodes?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to get all paths:

1. Get one iteration, as example root: `https://dev.azure.com/<org>/<team project name>/_apis/wit/classificationnodes/Iterations?api-version=5.1`. [Classification Nodes - Get an iteration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/classification%20nodes/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#get-an-iteration).
2. Check the `hasChildren` property. If it's true get this iteration with children (add depth to request). Example to get child for Iteration 1:  `https://dev.azure.com/<org>/<team project name>/_apis/wit/classificationnodes/Iterations/Iteration 1?$depth=1&api-version=5.1?api-version=5.1`
3. Or try to pass depth with your iteration tree level. Example to get 10 levels of children from the root: `https://dev.azure.com/<org>/<team project name>/_apis/wit/classificationnodes/Iterations?$depth=10&api-version=5.1`